# How to edit textfields that have been animated

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a navbar .Edit button that, when pressed, does an animation effect, moving the UI around in the VC, as well as enables interaction with the textfields.  Right now, when I select a textfield, after animation, everything jumps back to it's original position.

Here's the code I use the the animation. and I have a separate function that I use for returning the UI back to it's original position. Not sure if there is an easier way, but I ended up entering in the location/ size of the original positions.

```
func editingAnimation() {



    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {
        self.nameTextField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = false
        // button/ image position/ size
        self.profileImage.frame = CGRectMake(10, 25, 185, 185)
        self.genderButton.frame = CGRectMake(210, 110, 100, 100)
        self.catOrDogButton.frame = CGRect(x: 304, y: 104, width: 100, height: 100)

        // textfields position/ size
        self.nameTextField.frame = CGRectMake(200, 40, 204, 30)
        self.breedTextField.frame = CGRectMake(200, 75, 204, 30)
        self.birthDateTextField.frame = CGRectMake(200, 215, 204, 30)
        self.acquiredDateTextField.frame = CGRectMake(200, 250, 204, 30)
        self.colorTextField.frame = CGRectMake(200, 285, 204, 30)
        self.microchipTextField.frame = CGRectMake(200, 320, 204, 30)
        self.registrationTextField.frame = CGRectMake(200, 355, 204, 30)
        self.notesTextView.frame = CGRectMake(200, 390, 204, 250)

        // labels position/ size
        self.birthDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(80, 220, 115, 20)
        self.acquiredDateLabel.frame = CGRectMake(80, 255, 115, 20)
        self.colorLabel.frame = CGRectMake(80, 290, 115, 20)
        self.microchipIDLabel.frame = CGRectMake(80, 325, 115, 20)
        self.registrationIDLabel.frame = CGRectMake(80, 360, 115, 20)
        self.aboutYourPetLabel.frame = CGRectMake(80, 395, 115, 20)

        }, completion: nil)

}
```

I would also like to note, the two buttons I have towards the top, don't move position at all. In any case, any help would be greatly appreciated.  If there is any code I should add, just let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Are you using autolayout for these elements?

Comment: @SaintThread No I don't believe so. Unless it is an automatic feature of storyboard.  Sorry, I am still new to swift.  I didn't set anything up for autolayout.

Comment: Do you add these element programmatically ?

Comment: no, everything I am having animated, was added through Storyboard.